# How to install Slidewall?

Tags: software-installation

I have some issues downloading Slidewall.

I have entered the correct terminal commands, and have checked them several times to be sure, but when I actually try to install the program, I always get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package slidewall
```

Is there any way for me to install it successfully?

Comment: Slidewall isn't in the repositories..

Comment: @Seth actually it's. In the extras.

Answer (score 3):

The package `slidewall` is only available using the extra repository (or ppa), and only on **precise**. Installation method:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3E5C1192
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main" >> \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/extras.list'
sudo apt-get install slidewall
```

Sources:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/extras/precise/main/base/slidewall
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/extras?dist=precise

Answer (score 1):

What Commands did you use?

This is what i used

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fioan89/slidewall 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slidewall
```

If that does not work , it might be a 13.10 issue.